# Code with explanation on using the OpenCV for image classification using the SVM with python from Scratch

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, opencv

Could anyone share links and resources on Image classification using SVM(Support Vector Machine) from Scratch? Also, there should be the use of the OpenCV library.

I got one [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d73/tutorial_introduction_to_svm.html), where I am trying to understand the code. But, it's complicated for me.